# Вывод значения эллемента массива в атрибут

Tags: php, веб-программирование

```
echo '<option name="$row_core['nameM']">';
    echo $row_core['nameM'];

echo '</option>';
```

пытаюсь вывести в атрибут name значения массива
но ошибка :

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'nameM' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\technet\admin\index.php on line 67
```

Comment: покажи как пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

так все работает

```
echo '<option name="'. $row_core['nameM'] . '">';
    echo $row_core['nameM'];
echo '</option>';
```

Comment: Или так - 
`echo "<option name=\"$row_core['nameM']\">";
    echo $row_core['nameM'];
echo "</option>";`

Comment: @A.Gusev ваш пример не будет работать

Comment: Мой пример будет работать

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<option name=$row_core[nameM]>";
  echo $row_core['nameM'];
echo "</option>";
```